# How to fix kmeans error in r : 'more cluster centers than distinct data points'?

Tags: r

When I run my kmeans algorithm I get this error

```
Error in kmeans(dat[, -1], k) : 
more cluster centers than distinct data points.
```

How can this error be fixed? I am 99% sure my data points are distinct.
Here is my code

```
withinVar <- c() 
for (k in 2:30) { 
  km <- kmeans(dat[, -1], k) 
  withinVar <- c(withinVar, km$tot.withinss) 
}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How many rows are in your `dat` data.frame?

Comment: dim(unique(dat[,-1])); just check if it is more than k?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Max Gress. Could you provide the `dat` data.frame?

Comment: imageId mountain tree prettySky person child animal virginiaTech food entertainment city country building
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
3 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
4 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
5 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
6 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1                                 this is a sample of the first few rows of the data frame. The actual dimension of it is 31 observations to 13 variables.

Comment: The dimension of it is less then K. The dimension of that code is 27 observations to 12 variables.